# Android SOAP Parsing Example

Tags: android, soap

Does anyone have a good example of SOAP parsing on Android?

Comment: thanks hardik. your question help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parsing of Soap messages is not included in Android runtime, so it isn't really straightforward. You should use an external library.
I'm using [ksoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/).

If you search here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksoap2) you'll see many examples on how to use it. For instance [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data) .

Answer (score 2):

Also worth checking out [WSClient++](http://wsclient.neurospeech.com/). It generates all the stub and model objects and hides all the parsing and binding to objects.

I use it when I'm forced to use soap in Android. It's not free, but will save you a ton of time over ksoap2, which seems to need voodoo to get it working (that could of changed I last tried 1yr ago)

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the code above, including authentication:

```
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("serverIP", portNo), 
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this Code

```
      DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
     String responseString = null;
     try
     {

     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://services/?wsdl");
     httppost.setHeader("SOAPAction", "urn:getSearch");
     httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

     String strEnvelope = "SOAP BODY" ;

     HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(strEnvelope);
     httppost.setEntity(entity);
     ResponseHandler<String> strResponseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler(); 
     responseString = httpClient.execute(httppost, strResponseHandler);
     Log.d("Search", responseString);

     }
     catch (Exception objException)
     {
         throw objException ;

     }
     finally
     {
         httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
     }
```